# How to prevent $.ajax form from sending multiple emails?

Tags: contact-form, ajaxform

I have two email forms on one webpage. The form sends email correctly when submitted only once, but when I hit the submit button for the second time or more, not only the email with data is sent, but also additional empty emails. I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<form id="notify-form" name="notify-form" action="#" method = "post">
     <div class="input-group">
         <input class="input-field" type="email" id="email-notify" name="emailnotify" placeholder="Type your email..." required>
         <span class="input-label">
             <button class="btn-submit" onclick="ajax_news();"><i class="icon-arrow"></i></button>
         </span>
     </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
function ajax_news(){
var form = $('#notify-form'); //form id here
form.submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var form_newsstatus = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    var $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "process-news.php",
        data:{
           Email2:$form.find("input[name='emailnotify']").val() 
        },

        beforeSend: function(){
            form.append(form_newsstatus.html('Sending...').fadeIn());
        }
       }).done(function(data){
           form_newsstatus.html('Thank you! We will notify you soon!').delay(5210).fadeOut();
       });

  //delete messages when submit
    document.getElementById("email-notify").value= "";
}); 
}

function ajax_post(){
  //Similar code for the second form
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 ini_set("mail.log", "/tmp/mail.log");
 ini_set("mail.add_x_header", TRUE);

 //variables
 $email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Email2']));

 // Create the email and send the message
 $to = 'email@email.com';
 $email_subject = "Email subject";
 $email_body = "Email message:\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\n\n";
 $headers = "From: email@email.com\n"; 
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 

 if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){ echo "Mail sent!";} 
 else{ echo "Error, check your logs."; }
 return true;
```

Comment: do both forms have the same html / js?

Comment: on a side note, validation for the form should also be done on the backend. now to reset the form using jquery use `$( '#notify-form' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});` , this is not tested since i am not home but it should work

Comment: The second form collects name, email and message - HTML structure is the same, but the id and the input names are different and the submit button for the second form contains onclick="ajax_post();"
JS for the second form has different ids and input names...
but even if I remove one of the forms (both HTML and JS) the problem persists.